# Having issues with a powershell script and exporting to excel

Tags: powershell

My question is this, I am unsure if I have written this right as I am getting errors and no output in excel. Can you please guide me where I am messing up?

Below is the script that I am ATTEMPTING to write. I need to pull the following information:

- up-down status (using w32tm for that)
- list of servers
- up/down status (when it was stood up)
- when it was built
- last updated file folder
- server cert is not expired
- checking for full drive

```
    Import-Module activedirectory
    Import-Module psremoteregistry
    # Set your Active Directory filter
    $searchbase = Get-AdComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "(redacted ou here)" |ft
    
    # Define an array to store server information
    $server = @()
    
    #servers from AD
    $serversfromAD = Get-ADComputer -filter * -searchbase "(redacted ou here)" -properties Name, operatingsystem, operatingsystemservicepack, whenCreated, lastlogon, lastLogonTimestamp, lastlogondate
    
    # Iterate through the list of servers
    foreach ($server in $serversFromAD) {
        $serverData = New-Object PScustomObject -Property @{
            "ServerName" = $server.Name
            "OperatingSystem" = $server.OperatingSystem
            "InstallDate" = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server.Name).InstallDate
            "LastReboot" = [System.DateTime]::FromFileTime($server.LastLogonTimestamp)
            "ServerStatus" = ( (get-service -Name W32Time -ComputerName $server.name).Status -ne "Running")
            "TrellixDate" = (get-itemproperty "C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater").lastwritetime -le ((get-date).adddays(-2))
        }
    }
    
    $report += $temp
    
    $csvfile="C:\Scripttest\AD-All-Computers.csv"
    
    $report | export-csv -notypeinformation $csvfile
    "Wrote file for All Computers"
```

Comment: Hello, you forgot to include what the issues are. Ask a question.

Comment: What errors? Have you use the PowerShell ISE to step through each line, if so, which line exactly isn’t working? We obviously cannot debug your code for you unless we have an Active Directory domain ourselves. This probably should be moved to SO.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post ever on SE, I am still figuring this stuff out. I get
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.
get-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'W32Time'.

Comment: Some advice: Your goal right now is to make your question as thorough and complete as possible. So, use the EDIT button and add any info requested in the comments to the question itself, so that the question gets better and better.

Comment: Based on the error you've given, the problem isn't with exporting to CSV, but with finding the service you want to check. You need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you've listed mean you were not able to connect to the server. Both errors will happen for almost any connection issue, even if you just use the wrong computer name.

You could catch these with a basic connection test first. Here's an example where you just set the properties to "not available" instead of skipping the server entirely:

```
# Iterate through the list of servers
$report = foreach ($server in $serversFromAD) {

  # query remote server for properties
  try {
    Test-Connection $server.name -ErrorAction Stop

    $serverData = New-Object PScustomObject -Property @{
      "ServerName"      = $server.Name
      "OperatingSystem" = $server.OperatingSystem
      "InstallDate"     = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server.Name).InstallDate
      #...
  }}
  
  # but if connection fails, set properties to "Not Available" instead
  catch { 
    $serverData = New-Object PScustomObject -Property @{
      "ServerName"      = $server.Name
      "OperatingSystem" = $server.OperatingSystem
      "InstallDate"     = 'NotAvailable'
      # etc. for other properties
  }}
  
  return $ServerData
}

$report | Format-Table
```

---

+Side note that the `"TrellixDate"` check you have is checking on the local computer, and not the server